# Passing data back to wx frame from a twisted datagram protocol

Tags: python, wxpython, twisted

I want to display data from a twisted datagram protocol on a `wx` panel. It seems easy enough, but I'm pretty new to `wx` and have struggled to get this to work. I mostly followed [this](https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonAndTwisted) example. Here is a chunk of what I have so far:

```
import wx
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import wxreactor 
wxreactor.install()

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class BeagleProtocol(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.output = None
        gui.protocol = self
        self.gui = gui      
        
    def startProtocol(self):
        self.transport.connect("127.0.0.1", 1500)
        
    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        gui = self.gui
        print(repr(datagram))
        gui.SetStatusText(repr(datagram))     #<------ Why doesn't this work?
            
    def sendData(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class GUIframe(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, protocol, *args, **kwargs):
        # call the innit function of the parent class
        super(GUIframe, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.protocol = None
        self._led = False
        self._OnThrust = 1500
        self._OffThrust = 1500
        self._ThrusterOn = False
        
        # make a panel
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
           
        # Arrange the widgets in the panel with a box sizer
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.makeSuctionGUI(pnl))
        sizer.Add(self.makeDrawerGUI(pnl))        
        pnl.SetSizer(sizer)
        
        # make the menu bar
        self.makeMenuBar()
        
        # make a status bar
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.SetStatusText("This is some status text")
        
        # OTHER METHODS OMITTED

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Main program
    app = wx.App()
    frm = GUIframe( None, None, title="Hello World")
    frm.Show()
    
    reactor.registerWxApp(app)
    reactor.listenUDP(0, BeagleProtocol(frm))
    reactor.run()
```

I've been using Packet Sender and Wire Shark to test this. I don't get any errors, but when I send datagrams to the app, no change is visible on the frame. Data seems to be sent from the app just fine.

Comment: I suspect you have hit the `mainloop` issue. A gui has a mainloop which monitors and controls all of the `events` going on in a gui and you have left the mainloop to play with datagrams. Either create a new event for your updates in the gui and post events, rather than directly call functions or to just to get started try `yielding` to the gui mainloop. Try `wx.GetApp().Yield()` after setting the status text.

Comment: Do you see the side-effect of the `print` in `datagramReceived`?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, I just tried this with no change in result 
`def datagramReceived(self, datagram, addr):
        gui = self.gui
        print(repr(datagram))
        gui.SetStatusText(repr(datagram))
        wx.GetApp().Yield()`

@Jean-PaulCalderone, I don't see anything get printed in the console either.

Comment: If you are not printing anything, what makes you think the code is being executed? Try just printing a series of X's. If nothing prints, that code is not beng run and your problem lies elsewhere.